# Keep repeating the prompter questions with Inquirer.js based on answer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, prompt, inquirerjs

I'm using [Inquirer.js](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js) to create a `CLI's prompter` which allows `users` to enter/reply to some input/questions. In the last question, I want to add a feature that if the `user` replies `no` to `Are you done?` question, then the `prompter` will restart asking the questions until the `user` replies `yes`. I'm almost there with the functionality.

It's working, but only on the first time when I enter `no`. The second time I enter `no`, the prompter stops.

How can I run this on a loop to accomplish the desired behavior? What I'm doing wrong?

This is what I have some far:

```js
import inquirer from 'inquirer';

inquirer
  .prompt([
    // { bunch of other questions previously },
    {
      type: 'confirm',
      name: 'repeat_questions',
      message: 'Are you done?',
    },
  ])
  .then((answers) => {
    if (answers.repeat_questions) {
      return inquirer.prompt([
        // { bunch of other questions previously },
        {
          type: 'confirm',
          name: 'repeat_questions',
          message: 'Are you done?',
        },
      ]);
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    if (error.isTtyError) {
      throw new Error(`Prompt couldn't be render in current environment`);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is a recursive function:

```js
import inquirer from "inquirer";

const questions = [
  {
    type: "number",
    name: "children_count",
    message: "How many children do you have?",
  },
  {
    type: "input",
    name: "first_child_name",
    message: "What is the eldest child's name?",
  },
  {
    type: "confirm",
    name: "is_finished",
    message: "Are you done?",
  },
];

function getAnswers() {
  return inquirer.prompt(questions).then((answers) => {
    if (answers.is_finished) {
      return answers;
    } else {
      return getAnswers();
    }
  });
}

getAnswers()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch((error) => {});
```

The variable `repeat_questions` doesn't make sense, if the user says no to if they are done, `repeat_questions` is also no. So instead I renamed it to `is_finished`.